# Stored procedure Read xml file with namespaces

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, xml-namespaces

I am trying to read the following xml using a stored procedure in SQL server 2016.

```
DECLARE @xml as xml

SET @xml = '<ns:MT_FlexParams_SPICE xmlns:ns="urn:ptl.com:pi:imdl">
    <row>
        <ACCT>100043</ACCT>
        <BROL>10085437</BROLE>
        <STRTDAT>2019-11-01 00:00:00.0</STRTDAT>
        <ENDDAT>2021-05-15 00:00:00.0</ENDDAT>
        <DELDATE>1900-01-01 00:00:00.0</DELDATE>
        <DEF_ROLE> </DEF_ROLE>
        <BRASTA>10</BRASTA>
        <IRQID>10126</IRQID>
        <BRAUT_GRA> </BRAUT_GRA>
        <BRAUT_REV> </BRAUT_REV>
    </row>
    <row>
        <ACCT>100037</ACCT>
        <BROL>10085437</BROLE>
        <STRTDAT>2019-10-21 00:00:00.0</STRTDAT>
        <ENDDAT>2020-10-21 00:00:00.0</ENDDAT>
        <DELDATE>1900-01-01 00:00:00.0</DELDATE>
        <DEF_ROLE> </DEF_ROLE>
        <BRASTA>10</BRASTA>
        <IRQID>10106</IRQID>
        <BRAUT_GRA> </BRAUT_GRA>
        <BRAUT_REV> </BRAUT_REV>
    </row>
</ns:MT_FlexParams_SPICE>'

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:ptl.com:pi:imdl') 
SELECT @xml.value('(row/ACCT)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as ACCT;
```

But it is fetching null result. Could you please let me know the mistake that I am performing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is not well-formed, so I had to fix it.

You need to use `.nodes()` method to shred the XML into a rectangular structure.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML = N'<ns:MT_FlexParams_SPICE xmlns:ns="urn:ptl.com:pi:imdl">
    <row>
        <ACCT>100043</ACCT>
        <BROL>10085437</BROL>
        <STRTDAT>2019-11-01 00:00:00.0</STRTDAT>
        <ENDDAT>2021-05-15 00:00:00.0</ENDDAT>
        <DELDATE>1900-01-01 00:00:00.0</DELDATE>
        <DEF_ROLE>
        </DEF_ROLE>
        <BRASTA>10</BRASTA>
        <IRQID>10126</IRQID>
        <BRAUT_GRA>
        </BRAUT_GRA>
        <BRAUT_REV>
        </BRAUT_REV>
    </row>
    <row>
        <ACCT>100037</ACCT>
        <BROL>10085437</BROL>
        <STRTDAT>2019-10-21 00:00:00.0</STRTDAT>
        <ENDDAT>2020-10-21 00:00:00.0</ENDDAT>
        <DELDATE>1900-01-01 00:00:00.0</DELDATE>
        <DEF_ROLE>
        </DEF_ROLE>
        <BRASTA>10</BRASTA>
        <IRQID>10106</IRQID>
        <BRAUT_GRA>
        </BRAUT_GRA>
        <BRAUT_REV>
        </BRAUT_REV>
    </row>
</ns:MT_FlexParams_SPICE>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:ptl.com:pi:imdl' AS ns)
SELECT c.value('(ACCT/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as ACCT
    , c.value('(BROL/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') as BROL
FROM @xml.nodes('/ns:MT_FlexParams_SPICE/row') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+--------+----------+
|  ACCT  |   BROL   |
+--------+----------+
| 100043 | 10085437 |
| 100037 | 10085437 |
+--------+----------+
```

Comment: I have one more query. Is it possible to extract the string from this node of the xml <ns:MT_FlexParams_SPICE xmlns:ns="urn:ptl.com:pi:imdl">.

Comment: @RanitDas, please ask it as a separate new question.